# TabCtrl_GetItem macro not working as expected

Tags: c++, winapi, tabbed-interface

I'm creating a basic notepad program, and when the user clicks close, I want it to ask the user if they want to save the current document opened. I'm using a tabbed interface, and trying to retrieve the filename ( text on tab ) so I have a MessageBox that says "Would you like to save: untitled.txt" or similar. I'm having trouble getting the file name.  This is what I currently have:

```
case ID_FILE_CLOSE:  // When the close button is clicked
  {
    HWND hEdit, hTabs;
    hTabs = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_MAIN_TAB );
    int curTab = TabCtrl_GetCurSel( hTabs );

    TCITEM curtitem;
    TabCtrl_GetItem( hTabs, curTab, &curtitem );

    // Check for file name
    MessageBox( hwnd, curtitem.pszText, "Test", MB_OK );
  }
  break;
```

This is the error I keep getting in a popup box with Break, Continue, Ignore buttons:

Unhandled exception at 0x7597d298 in notepadpremium.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xcccccccc.

I'm using MS Visual C++ Express 2010.

I also have a listbox with the filenames that also show the extension ( almost like notepad++ document switcher ) and tried LB_GETITEMDATA through a message, but that always returned blank. I think that was because I use LB_ADDSTRING to add it to the listbox. ( the listbox and tabs are interconnected, when you click on a file in the listbox, it changes to the corresponding tab ). Why isnt my code working the way it should?

Answer (score 3):

[Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> pitem 
>   Type: LPTCITEM
>
> Pointer to a TCITEM structure that specifies the information to retrieve and receives information about the tab. **When the message is sent, the mask member specifies which attributes to return. If the mask member specifies the TCIF_TEXT value, the pszText member must contain the address of the buffer that receives the item text, and the cchTextMax member must specify the size of the buffer.**

You are not initializing the `TCITEM` at all.  You need to tell `TabCtrl_GetItem()` what data to retrieve, and more importantly what buffer *you* provide to receive that data into. You are not doing any of that, you are passing random data to `TabCtrl_GetItem()`, which is why it crashes.

Try this instead:

```
case ID_FILE_CLOSE:  // When the close button is clicked
  {
    HWND hTabs = GetDlgItem( hwnd, IDC_MAIN_TAB );

    int curTab = TabCtrl_GetCurSel( hTabs );
    TCHAR szFileName[MAX_PATH+1] = {0};

    TCITEM curtitem = {0};
    curitem.mask = TCIF_TEXT;
    curitem.pszText = szFileName;
    curitem.cchTextMax = MAX_PATH;

    if (TabCtrl_GetItem( hTabs, curTab, &curtitem ))
    {
      // also from the documentation:
      //
      // "the control may change the pszText member of the structure
      // to point to the new text instead of filling the buffer with
      // the requested text. The control may set the pszText member
      // to NULL to indicate that no text is associated with the item."
      //
      // which means you cannot rely on the szFileName[] buffer actually
      // containing the filename, you have to use whatever buffer the
      // TCITEM is actually pointing at, which may or may not be the
      // szFileName buffer...

      MessageBox( hwnd, curitem.pszText, TEXT("Test"), MB_OK );
    }
  }
  break;
```

As for your ListBox issue, you said you are using `LB_ADDSTRING` to add strings to the ListBox, but are using `LB_GETITEMDATA` to retrieve them. That is wrong. You need to use `LB_GETTEXTLEN` and `LB_GETTEXT` instead. `LB_GETITEMDATA` is used to retrieve user-defined data that was added to the ListBox using `LB_SETITEMDATA`.